# Can we use list or set in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

I have a simple question that can we use list or set in domain entity of neo4j If it can be done that how can i use it.

```
My Relation ship entity code is:

import com.volcare.domain.auth.User
import com.volcare.domain.global.BaseEntity;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.EndNode;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.GraphId;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.RelationshipEntity;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.StartNode;

@RelationshipEntity(type="HAS_RESOURCES")
class UserRequestResource extends  BaseEntity{

    @StartNode User user
    @EndNode Resource resource

    Boolean isBlackListed
    Boolean isAppliedByUser
    Boolean isApproved = false
    Boolean isRejected = false

    Date requiredOnDate
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Collections as properties are converted into arrays as node-properties, so all the elements have to be of the **same type** and of one of the **supported types: numerics, boolean, string**